# Angular router multiple params as variables

Tags: angular

My router configuration will look something like this:

```
        {
            path: ':firstVariable',
            component: FirstComponent
        },
        {
            path: ':secondVariable',
            component: SecondComponent
        }
```

From my understanding, when i type domain/:something in url, it will always go to the FirstComponent since router can't know in which of the 2 paths we are referring to so it goes to the first one.

My question is, can I somehow redirect it to the desired component? This is not my approach, this is client's wish and it needs to be done this way.

Answer (score 2):

don't take it as variable take it as route.

```
{
            path: 'firstVariable',
            component: FirstComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'secondVariable',
            component: SecondComponent
        }
```

or

```
 {
                path: ':firstVariable',
                component: HomeComponent
            }
```

in home component check if param is first display first component else display second component.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't because I will have an infinite amount of variable values. firstVariable can be anything and secondVariable can be anything. And they are pretty similar since both of them are slugs.. I honestly think this can't be done in a way my client wants.